# Объект с динамическими ключами в TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть интерфейс объекта, где значения всех ключей типа `string` и одного `boolean`:

```
interface ObjectInterface {
    [key: string]: string;
    booleanKey: boolean;
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы TypeScript не выдавал за ошибку, что значение ключа booleanKey должно быть `string`?

Для примера вот так все работает:

```
interface ObjectInterface {
        [key: string]: string | boolean;
        booleanKey: boolean;
    }
```

Comment: Тип any, не пробовали?

Comment: такое себе решение проблемы, скорее её сокрытие

Answer (score 0):

```
interface BoolKey{
    booleanKey: boolean;
}

type ObjectInterface = BoolKey | {
    [key: string]: string
}
```

Разве что так. По другому не придумал

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=21#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHt0BsDSECeA3gFDJnIBGmWEcIe+AXJdbSANzEC+xxY+ABxQB5CgCsICMAElw0eEmQBeNNQbIAZMhLlkAbQDWBZgGcwUUAHMAuqfNXuxBOhBnkAR2XbS5KtjYMzOYArhAAND5k7u7MAOQAjPGx3MhwJsiiElKykLCIEEA

Comment: перепутал знак, исправил, но он как-то странно работает: 
Нормально работает
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&ssl=12&ssc=3&pln=12&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHt0BsDSECeA3gFDJnIBGmWEcIe+AXJdbSANzEC+xxY+ABxQB5CgCsICMAElw0eEmQBeNNQbIAPshLlkAbQDWBZgGcwUUAHMAuqfNXuxBOhBnkAR2aiJU2ZFiIKCo65FTYbAzM5gCuEAA0pOTunsgA5ACMAEypCbog0QC2zIQ8XOxAA

Comment: А так уже не работает: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHt0BsDSECeA3gFDJnIBGmWEcIe+AXJdbSANzEC+xxY+ABxQB5CgCsICMAElw0eEmQBeNNQbIAPshLlkAbQDWBZgGcwUUAHMAuqfNXuxBOhBnkAR2XbS5KtjYMzOYArhAAND5k7u7MAOQAjABMsRG6IMEAtsyEPFzIcCbIohJSspCwiBDsQA

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: перепутал знак©  - не вводи в заблуждение ни себя ни нас

Comment: что ты имеешь в виду? Перепутал знак объединения и альтерации, где я ввожу вас в заблуждение?

Comment: Ого, работает о_О

Answer (score 0):

Простите, но я не вижу вашу схему поэтому буду ориентироваться в слепую, судя по двум другим примерам выше, у вас объект, а они предлагают работать с массивом. Так же не увидел ошибку которую показывает TypeScript.

Если схема вот такая:

```json
[
   {
       name: true,
       booleanKey: false
   },
   {
       data: 'PostgresQL',
       booleanKey: false
   }
]
```

Тогда нужно объявить, что у вас объект:

```
interface ObjectInterface {
   [key: string]: unknown | boolean;
   booleanKey: boolean;
}

interface Items extends Array<ObjectInterface>{}
```

Вот интерфейс **Items** и нужно передать там где вы ждёте объект, и там не обязательно string ожидать, где ключ точно будет строкой, более гибкий вариант. Напишите пожалуйста, правильно ли я вас понял.
Заранее благодарю :)

Comment: Ну и что это за бред?

Answer (score -2):

Ключи, которые заранее не определены нужно помещать в конец интерфейса.

`interface ObjectInterface { booleanKey: boolean; [key: string]: string; }`

Comment: И чем же это поможет?